# Generating a css gradient with single color

Tags: css, css-gradients

I am trying to generate a gradient using one single color and then varying the brightness or some other related variable.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: what are the other related variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alpha channel for this purpose. Consider color "#428383":

```css
div {
  background-color: #428383; /* for browsers without gradient support */
  background: linear-gradient(#42838344, #428383ff);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use a back/white layer on the top of your single color as a gradient

```css
html {
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(255 255 255/50%),rgb(0 0 0/50%)),
    red; /* here is your single color */
}
```

Another idea is to use `color-mix()` to create different shades from the same color

```css
html {
  --c: red; /* the main color */

  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,
      color-mix(in srgb,var(--c), #fff 30%), /* we mix with white for brighter */
      color-mix(in srgb,var(--c), #000 30%)  /* we mix with black for darker */
     )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can by use "transparent" as a color

`background: linear-gradient(transparent, #9198e5);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use RGBA

```
background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(2,0,36,0.3) 100%);
```

`0.3` will dim the color

If you want to add stop points at 0%, 30%, 100% with three different brightness

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(2,0,36,0.4) 30%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vary brightness or saturation of a single color, you may be better of using `hsl()` instead of hex or rgb values:

```css
.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(193,82%,56%), hsl(193,82%,26%));
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

HSL stands for Hue, Saturation and lightness or luminance and is just another way of describing a color. This way you can easily alter saturation and brightness without actually altering the colors hue. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV